# web service method parameters

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to create a web service, in .NET, where a sender can send data, as query string, and the parameter names are encoded. Below is an example of the URL to send the data:
http://*hostname*/Processor/Service.asmx/InsertReport?A%2dE3%2dName=John

The method InsertReport needs to have A-E3-Name as a parameter.

How do I declare the parameter to receive the value John?

Comment: Please keep in mind that when you're sending data in a query string, that there may be a maximum character limit depending on the server and/or browser. That's something to consider if you're going to host it with IIS. I would reference this answer to get an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string#answer-812962

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve query string parameter values in C# by:

```
Request.QueryString["A-E3-Name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Test1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Test2></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answers the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass these in as actual parameters for your webmethod (eg. your ASMX has a method with parameters that correspond to your querystring parameter names), you need to rethink your parameter names.  Even if you url-decoded them, you can't have a C# method with parameters named A-B-3-Something.  Try creating a method with a parameter like that and you will notice that it won't compile.

Perhaps if you describe what you are trying to do we can offer a better solution.